# Autocomplete value from angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ide

What if I made a service (as 'myService') in 'A.js' and Try to use it in 'B.js'.

Is there any IDE or editor that can autocomplete 'myService' even tho I type only 'myS'?

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ does this for you.

If you use [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/) comments you get java style code completion.

Answer (score 0):

Webstorm is good javascript IDE , it has very good features autocomplete , debug and many like this.

you can use service from any js file , in angular js you need to use mechanism called **DEPENDENCY INJECTION** , using dependency injection you can inject your service in controller (same js or different js) , and you can access it.

for more information visit this link

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services